# Detecting CSV Headers when creating a DataBricks Delta Table?

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

Needless to say, I'm new to Spark DataBricks and Delta.

I'm trying to create a Delta table using %sql from a simple csv where the first row is a header row. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the initial CREATE TABLE to recognise the header column in the CSV (Just to note, I've been using the DataBricks quickstart as a guide - https://docs.databricks.com/delta/quick-start.html)

The code I've got in my Databricks notebook is

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE people
USING delta
LOCATION '/dbfs/mnt/mntdata/DimTransform/People.csv'
```

I have tried using the TBLPROPERTIES ("headers" = "true") but with no success - see below

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE people
USING delta
TBLPROPERTIES ("headers" = "true")
AS SELECT *
FROM csv.'/mnt/mntdata/DimTransform/People.csv'
```

In both cases, the csv data is loaded into the table but the header row is just included in the data as the first standard row.

Any ideas how I'd get this %sql CREATE TABLE to recognise the first/header row as a header when loading from a csv?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you have to do a small workaround because you are using CSV file, not a JSON or PARQUET, These files have schema and csv no.

So I suggest to do that::

```
%sql
drop table if exists tempPeopleTable ;
CREATE TABLE tempPeopleTable
  USING csv
  OPTIONS (path "/mnt/mntdata/DimTransform/People.csv", header "true", inferSchema "true");

CREATE TABLE people
USING delta
AS SELECT * FROM tempPeopleTable;

drop table if exists tempPeopleTable;
```

Comment: Thank you Fabio, that is a good/ clear suggestion and I'm happy to roll with it if that is the best work-around. That said, whilst I agree csv has no defined schema it does have a header row which is generally recognised as the way you define your "schema" in csv. I'd assumed/ hoped that Delta would have a mechanism for inferring the schema from the csv headers in the same way your suggested code infers the schema when creating TABLE tempPeopleTable.

Comment: Actually the problem is not the create delta table the problem is select * from csv.`file` here I did not find a way to 'say' to databricks that the first column is the schema